# how to enable color highlighting for interactive git rebase on mac

Tags: git

Color highlighting works for everything else in git (e.g. status, log, branch name etc).  Just not when I do an interactive rebase.

This sort of makes sense because interactive rebase happens within a text editor, where other interactions are just terminal output.  But I think I remember highlighting working by default in git bash on windows, so there must be a way on mac.

I would like it to color code pick vs squash vs fixup etc.

As a shot in the dark, I tried setting color param `interactive` to `true` and `auto` in my `~/.gitconfig`, and tried supplying some color values explicitly, but this had no effect:

```
[color]
    branch = auto
    diff = auto
    status = auto
    ui = auto
    interactive = true
[color "interactive"]
    pick = yellow
    squash = green
    fixup = cyan
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The highlighting in an editor is not controlled by git's configuration. Highlighting works by default in git bash because it comes with a vim pre-configured with git syntax files.

Assuming you are using vim for the git editor on mac, first try enabling vim syntax highlighting by adding `syntax on` to `~/.vimrc`.

Failing that, you may need to download and install [git syntax files](https://github.com/tpope/vim-git).

Comment: Your answer led me to https://superuser.com/a/472240/323255, which suggested to simply add `syntax on` to `~/.vimrc`, which did the trick.  No downloading necessary.